# Creating a Weather Update Application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to create application that will show the weather update of the city.I have tried this my 2 ways

1.I have used AsyncTask for that with `.get()` so wait till the response comes from the API that i am using to show waether update.

2.In the AsyncTask in the `onPostExecute` i have done all setting of the values that i have received from the server.

But the issue is on the 1 way it is taking to much of time to open up the activity till the response comes from the server .

On the 2 way the activity opens up quickly but the values are updated after the response comes from the server.

I want to do it as it open up quickly without taking time.So is there any other way we can do this so that it don't take time .

Please suggest what approach i have to follow to get this,can we use some kind of caching to save the images url and temp,humidity

Answer (score 0):

Use the Volley library, there's a Google IO 2013 talk on it and lots of examples you can search for.

[Volley - Google IO 2013](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728&ei=wLdPUqi5Jeel0AWTsICoBg&usg=AFQjCNEyT1AnZrgVSp1BDzOBwgHglo9UpQ&sig2=Da3nPIBg0kHEkq19APp5HA&bvm=bv.53537100,d.d2k)

Comment: will you help me to use this ...any idea or sample code you have to convert asynk task in this

Comment: @Rahul here's an example http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library. you can also use a service

Comment: @Raghunandan service ??I didn't get you